# Show div element if select option from one select AND another select

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-select

I want to know how to show one element after I select option from one select and then select option from another select. If I have 2 selected options the div need to show, else to hide. I tried this, but it is not working. How can I do it with change function or something else ? Thanks.

```
if ($('select.one option').is(':selected') && $('select.two option').is(':selected')) {
    jQuery('.box').show();
 } else { 
         jQuery('.box').hide();
         }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap your code in a "change" event listener.

There are several ways of doing it, but this should work fine.

```
$('select.one').change(function() {
    if ($('select.one option').is(':selected') && $('select.two option').is(':selected')) {
        $('.box').show();
     } else {
        $('.box').hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(document).on("change","select.one,select.two",function(){

     if ($('select.one option').is(':selected') && $('select.two option').is(':selected')) {
        jQuery('.box').show();
     } else { 
        jQuery('.box').hide();
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/axaryfb2/

```js
$('select').change(function(){
   if (($('select.one option').is(':selected') && $('select.one option:selected').val() != "") && ($('select.two option').is(':selected') && $('select.two option:selected').val() != "")) {
      $('.box').show();
   } else { 
      $('.box').hide();
   }
});
```

```css
.box{
  width: 100px;
  height:100px;
  background: blue;
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="one">
  <option value="">Select Option</option>
  <option value="test1">test 1</option>
  <option value="test2">test 2</option>
</select>

<select class="two">
  <option value="">Select Option</option>
  <option value="testA">test A</option>
  <option value="testB">test B</option>
</select>

<div class="box">

</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('select').change(function(){
   if ($('select.one option').is(':selected') && $('select.two option').is(':selected')) {
      $('.box').show();
   } else { 
      $('.box').hide();
   }
});
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Ive included a listener on all `select` elements on the page that have the class `demoSelect`.

You dont want to add a listener to all `select` elements on your page as you may have other `select` elements that dont require the same logic. Wrapping them in a class and then selecting on the class instead allows for this.

```js
//use the on() method to attach event handlers, this replaces the live(), delegate() and bind() methods from previous JQuery versions
$(".demoSelect").on("change", function()
{
    //if values for both dropdowns are set to "1"
    if( $("#one").val() == "1" && $("#two").val() == "1") 
    { 
       //show the div
       $(".box").show();
    } 
    else 
    {  
       //hide the div
       $(".box").hide(); 
    }
});
```

```css
.container
{
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 70px;
}

.padding
{
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- example of select options that are affected by the above javascript !-->
<div class="container">
  <div class="padding">
    <span>
    This select group uses the script because of the '.demoSelect' class
    </span><br/>
    <select id="one" class="demoSelect">
      <option> Please Select </option>
      <option> 1 </option>
      <option> 2 </option>
    </select>
     <select id="two" class="demoSelect">
        <option> Please Select </option>
        <option> 1 </option>
        <option> 2 </option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="box padding" hidden>test</div>
</div><br/>

<!-- example of select options that arent affected by the above javascript !-->
<div class="container">
    <div class="padding">
      <span>
      This select group is unaffected by the script 
      </span><br/>
      <select id="separateSelectOptionOne">
        <option> Please Select </option>
        <option> 1 </option>
        <option> 2 </option>
      </select>
      <select id="separateSelectOptionTwo">
        <option> Please Select </option>
        <option> 1 </option>
        <option> 2 </option>
      </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

More info on the `on()` method [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: Let me make one last change, instead of using the change() method we should use the on() method.